# C#, DirectShow -- SDK for video capture

Tags: c#, sdk, directshow, video-capture

I must write a simple program in C# to show on the screen video which was capturing from external card which is named: iEi HDC-304E. It has 4 hdmi inputs and I've got 4 cameras which are streaming video via hdmi. I'm working on Windows 7 and Visual Studio.

My question is: has anybody used this card or knows how to start implementing the code in C#? My main problem is cannot connect to the card from C#.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: That's too broad, and hardware specific in the same time. Presumably you need to add more information, what have you tried in particular.

Comment: You write "video which was caputring" - that means you have already a mp4 or avi file? So no need to deal with card directly or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi, I have got already mpg file which is saving via this card. And I think about create such a program which capture this stream. Maybe Can I create the program which imitate a mpg file and this get stream to its memory ? Any one has that problem?